# how to store current user in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-authorization

I have a solution with the following projects in Visual Studio:
- MVC client project that connects to API project
- API project using using EF for idendity and for rest connect to Access project
- Access project using dapper to connect to SQL db

When I go to the login page in the MVC project I can login by using the API service. In return I can get user information.

I want to use this user information to store so that when going to other pages in MVC and connecting again to the API, I can sent the token as authorization.

How would I store this token in MVC? Or is there a better approach for this?

I was reading that keeping this information in a session would be a risk.

Comment: And how do you currently authenticate to your web API? Is a JWT Bearer token?

Comment: Hi Kebek, sorry I didn't include that information. Yes, I use a JWT bearer token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to store token one way or another in the MVC application.

The most common way is to store it in `sessionStorage` and they add it to the `Authorization` header when calling the API on every request

Comment: Thanks, did a little further looking into this and found a nuget package called Microsoft.Aspnetcore.session works perfect.